# Could I use few queries in another query in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

For example, I have two queries:

```
query FirstOne {
    city {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

and

```
query SecondOne {
    person {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
query CombinedQuery {
    FirstOne
    SecondOne
}
```

I want to reduce query duplications because if I can't create a query like `CombinedQuery` I will need to create it in this way:

```
query CombinedQuery {
    city {
        id
        name
    }
    person {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

From my perspective - this query is bad.

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments

Comment: Thank you, I know about fragments, but in this case, they still provide for duplicates. Maybe there is exist a better way?